# How can I get my Task List to display a list of my TODO statements?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, development-environment, todo, tasklist

I have a project that is "littered" with TODO statements in this format:

```
//TODO - remove directive if needed later
```

When I select View > Task List in that project, though, it is empty.

Selecting Tools > Options... > Environment > Task List, "TODO" is in the Token list with a priority of Normal. What else need I do to get the TODOs to display in the Task List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top Left of the Task List: choose "Comments" from the ComboBox.